# Generate a vector of repeated values based on the values of another vector in base R

Tags: r, vector

**Sample data**

```
batch <- c(rep(1,3), rep(2,4), rep(3,5))
batch
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3

alpha <- c(0.05, 0.04, 0.03)
```

**Problem Statement**

I'd like to create a vector, say `alphai`, that repeats the ith element of `alpha` the number of times it appears in `batch` at a given value (e.g. for batch = 1, the 1st value of alpha should be repeated the number of times 1 appears). The desired output should look like this:

```
alpha
[1] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03
```

Please provide base R only solutions, thanks!

**EDIT**

I would like the code provided to work in batch cases where batch could be either a non-increasing sequencing or a sequence that's non-contiguous (i.e. 1,3,4,5,etc.)

```
batch2 <- c(rep(1,3), rep(3, 4), rep(4,5))
batch2
[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

`alpha` should still be

```
[1] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03
```

Comment: As an aside, `batch` can be created this way `rep(1:3, 3:5)`

Comment: good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to use `rep` with `table`.

```
rep(alpha, table(batch))
#[1] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03
```

This would be helpful when `batch` does not follow the sequence `1:3`. For example,

```
batch <- rep(10:8, 3:5)
batch
#[1] 10 10 10  9  9  9  9  8  8  8  8  8

rep(alpha, table(batch))
#[1] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.03 0.03
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a more generalizable solution. Normally, the batches should be ordered starting from 1 in the data, but in the edge case of "dumb" user, this solution would cover that!

Answer (score 4):

The index can be used for replicating.  In `R`, indexing starts from 1.  So, if we specify multiple 1s, it is extracting the elements in the 'alpha' object from the 1st position multiple times, similarly for other index.  Note that an index of 0 will be skipped as there is no element

```
alpha[batch]
```

Comment: @latlio It is better to provide a more general example because when somebody answers the question, it is based on the example provided

Comment: I initially accepted your answer, and I don't know the SO etiquette that well yet, but I couldn't have foreseen this edge case, and @Ronak Shah's solution made me realize this edge case, so his answer (despite me not providing a general example) ended up being more generalizable. Is your answer more "correct" than his or his more "correct" than yours? I wish I could accept both answers. If I were to edit the question to include a more general case, would you return your vote? Just wondering about SO etiquette here, and what a vote actually means

Comment: OK, I wonder if SO etiquette would dictate if you edited your solution to also include the general case, `alpha[match(batch, sort(unique(batch))]`, then I'd accept yours because I would want to point future SO users who come across this question to pick the most generalizable and straightforward solution and also because I did accept your answer initially.

Comment: @latlio that's okay.  There is always a tradeoff in choosing for general solution vs that works for the example.  In this case, I choose this because it is very compact and I assume that your case fits well based on the example.  If the example was a bit more general, would have come up with something different.  My point is not about accepting solution.  You can choose whichever works for you best.